# Как удалить последовательные дубликаты из списка?

Tags: python

Есть список

```
list = [1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,2]
```

Надо "слить" соседние элементы, чтобы получилось

```
list = [1,2,3,4,2]
```

Как можно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 7):

Самый простой способ - использовать [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Он и предназначен для таких случаев - возвращает итератор с последовательными элементами и их количеством.

```
from itertools import groupby

old_list = [1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,2]

groupped = groupby(old_list)

print([elem for elem, grouper in groupped ])

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```

Если нужно узнать количество последовательных элементов, то можно поступить так:

```
for elem, grouper in groupped :
    print(elem, len(list(grouper)))

>>> 1 3
>>> 2 1
>>> 3 1
>>> 4 1
>>> 2 3
```

Comment: Плюс. Можно ещё: `uniq = map(itemgetter(0), groupby(list_))`

Answer (score 0):

Простейший вариант для начинающих:

```
list = [1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,2]
result = []
prev = None
for a in list:
    if a != prev:
        result.append(a)
        prev = a
print(result)
```

А вот вариант с той же логикой, но посложнее, с генераторами списков:

```
list = [1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,2]
def gen(lst):
    prev = None
    for a in lst:
        if a != prev:
            prev = a
            yield a

print([x for x in gen(list)])
```

Comment: OrderedDict сожрет все дубликаты, не только последовательные

Comment: @m9_psy Упс... Верно. Что-то я сегодня дебил...