# Как узнать количество одинаковых последовательных элементов в строке?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Имеется простой алгоритм дешифрования, составить его проблем не было.

Что мы делаем? Мы читаем строки и для каждой буквы, после которой стоит число мы делаем преобразование `word[0] * int(word[1:])`. То есть дублируем букву указанное количество раз.

Код такой:

```
import re


def readfile(filename):
    result = []

    with open (filename, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            line = re.findall(r'\w\d*', line)
            result.append(line)

    return result


def decrypt(lines):
    result = []

    for line in lines:
        for word in line:
            source_line = word[0] * int(word[1:])
            result.append(source_line)
    return result


def encrypt(lines):
    pass


def writefile(filename, lines):
    with open (filename, "w") as file:
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line)


lines = readfile("input.txt")
decrypted_lines = decrypt(lines)
writefile("output.txt", decrypted_lines)
```

Код работает, на входных данных

```
a2b4c3f5
c2b1m5v6
```

Получается выход:

```
aabbbbcccfffffccbmmmmmvvvvvv
```

Вопрос в следующем: как реализовать алгоритм шифрования, то есть поиск повторяющихся букв подряд. И при это реализовать его максимально эффективно?

То есть как максимально эффективно из, например, такой строки:

```
aabbbbccceeeeeff
```

Получить такую:

```
a2b4c3e5f2
```

Comment: Не стоит называть такой подход "криптографией".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить последовательные дубликаты из списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Вам нужно из `aabbbbcccfffff` получить `a2b4c3f5` ?

Comment: @Alban в точку!

Comment: @m9_psy почему же не стоит называть такой подход криптографией? Этот подход вполне можно отнести к **симметричному шифрованию**. Только добавить соль в виде, например, коэффициента множителя, и всё

Comment: @Kit Scribe думаю m9_psy прав, ибо это врядли будет являтся симметричным шифрованием, т.к. тут не требуется никакой ключ для шифровки/расшифровки.

Comment: Ну давайте теперь любое сжатие шифрованием называть :|

Comment: @AGS17 я, наверное, не очень понятно выразился. Я же говорю, добавить коэффициент или соль, чтобы преобразование было таким, например: `word[0] * int(word[1:]) * k`. Чем не симметричное шифрование?

Comment: @KitScribe `k` подберётся очень быстро, в большинстве случаев вообще с первого раза

Comment: @andreymal тем не менее, такой подход останется подходом с симметричным шифрованием не смотря на его слабость.

Comment: @KitScribe это сугубо учебное задание. На практике не так уж и много слов с повторяющимися подряд символами. К примеру, мой ком2ентарий сейчас "зашифрован" вашим "криптографическим" подходом, но вы можете без проблем прочесть его без дешифровки. Да и как вы будете "шифровать" числовую строку?

Comment: @AGS17 да! Именно! Это задание не для реальной практики и жизни (в исключительных случаях ради фана можно специфические данные шифровать). А все накинулись так, будто я продал идеалы всех вокруг за все деньги мира и всё забрал себе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно в 1 строку вот так:

```
from itertools import groupby

input_str = "aaaaccvvvvvvvbdp"

groupped_str = groupby(input_str)

result = "".join("".join((elem, str(len(list(grouper))))) for elem, grouper in groupped_str)

print(result)

>>> a4c2v7b1d1p1
```

Можно самую малость понятней:

```
result = []

for elem, grouper in groupped_str:
    result.append("".join((elem, str(len(list(grouper))))))

print(result)
```

[groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) возвращает повторяющиеся элементы и их количество - идеальный кандидат для решения и самому счетчиков никаких писать не нужно.

Comment: Ещё вариант: `rle = ''.join([c+str(len(list(same))) for c, same in groupby(text)])`

Answer (score 2):

Никаких особых уловок здесь нет. Просто пройти за линию по строке и упаковать:

```
string = 'sssssssssqqqqqqqffff'
currCh = string[:1]
currCount = 1
result = ''
for ch in string[1:]:
    if ch != currCh:
        result += (currCh + str(currCount))
        currCh = ch
        currCount = 1
    else:
        currCount += 1
result += (currCh + str(currCount))

print result
```

Результат:

```
s9q7f4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(line:str) -> str:
    decrypt = ''
    for i in line:
        if i not in decrypt:
            decrypt += f'{i}{line.count(i)}'
    return decrypt
```

**Результат**:

```
a2b4c3e5f2
```

Возможно есть решение проще, или этот код можно упростить. Но суть понятна.

Можно еще так:

```
string = 'aaaaccаааааvvvvрррррvvуууууvbdp'
result = "".join("".join((elem, str(string.count(elem)))) for elem in set(string))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s,n = 0,input()+' '
for i in n:
    if n[0] != i:
        print(n[0],s,end='',sep='')
        s,n = 0,i
    s += 1
```

Проще всего наверно так.